# Error when trying to use pango with imagemagick on OSX

Tags: imagemagick, osx-lion, pango

I am wanting to use imagemagick to add watermarks to photographs. I am using OSX and Python scripts for the code and was trying the code from  (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango_markup) currently I am struggling to understand why I can't get the images to appear.

```
serinitus:nppPhotos ns$ convert -background lightblue -gravity center -size 180x \
>           pango:"The <b>bold</b> and <i>beautiful</i>" \
>           pango_formatting.gif
convert: unable to open image `The <b>bold</b> and <i>beautiful</i>': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2658.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PANGO' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `pango_formatting.gif' @error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3187.
serinitus:nppPhotos ns$
```

Installed versions are ImageMagick 6.8.9-7 Q16 x86_64 2014-09-14 and pango-1.36.7 via homebrew.

I have tried re-installing ImageMagick with the --with-pango flag.

I'm down to one of two options: I'm missing something really obvious with the command line (even thought I copied/pasted it in), or there is a config error with the way that brew is installing imagemagick on OSX Lion.

Comment: Is Pango installed correctly? Try `convert -list format | grep -i pango` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: That was the issue - if you want to propose as an answer, I'll flag it as such (and apologies for the delay in responding!)

Comment: What did you find was the problem? I've got the same issue.

Comment: I had to reinstall Pango - there was a problem with the installation, but I don't recall exactly what at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me as though Pango is not installed. Either of the following two commands will tell you if ImageMagick is aware of Pango:

```
convert -list format
identify -list format
```

**Output:**

```
Format  Module    Mode  Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3FR  DNG       r--   Hasselblad CFV/H3D39II
  AAI* AAI       rw+   AAI Dune image
   AI  PDF       rw-   Adobe Illustrator CS2
  ART* ART       rw-   PFS: 1st Publisher Clip Art
  ARW  DNG       r--   Sony Alpha Raw Image Format
  AVI  MPEG      r--   Microsoft Audio/Visual Interleaved
  AVS* AVS       rw+   AVS X image
  BGR* BGR       rw+   Raw blue, green, and red samples
 BGRA* BGR       rw+   Raw blue, green, red, and alpha samples
  BMP* BMP       rw-   Microsoft Windows bitmap image
  ...
  PAM* PNM       rw+   Common 2-dimensional bitmap format
PANGO* PANGO     ---   Pango Markup Language
```

Or, if you dislike looking through lists:

```
identify -list format | grep -Ei "Description|pango"

Format  Module    Mode  Description
 PANGO* PANGO     ---   Pango Markup Language
```

You are looking for an `r` for `read` and a `w` for `write` in the column headed `Mode`. As you can see, nor do I have Pango :-)

Comment: It was a problem with the Pango install. Now fixed. 
Joys of computers :-S

Comment: Is this intended to be an answer?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r Yes, it is actually the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

I made it work with the following commands on El Capitan:
brew update

```
brew uninstall --force pango

brew rm gobject-introspection

brew deps imagemagick --with-pango

brew install imagemagick --build-from-source --with-pango
```

Comment: Great answer, it's working. The only thing I had to also do is `brew uninstall imagemagick` before re-installing.

Comment: 2023: `Error: invalid option: --with-pango`

Answer (score 2):

`brew install imagemagick --build-from-source --with-pango`

Doesn't work anymore, the options have been removed, github issue for reference
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510

They might reimplement the option if someones comes up with a good solution

In the meantime you can try this

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install pango librsvg
brew install cairo --build-from-source
```

If you already have the packages installed try `brew reinstall package_name`

Comment: `Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me (on `Catalina`), but it worked via macports (thanks to https://east.fm/posts/imagemagick-pango/index.html): `sudo port install imagemagick +pango`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried in all sorts of ways, because I really need it for a script I was working with. This worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -e

docker run -v "$(pwd)":/work -v "${TMPDIR}":"${TMPDIR}" -w /work cospaia/magick-pango-babashka convert "$@"
```

Won't work for all use cases, for sure. But anyway.

See: [ImageMagick with Pango on MacOS Ventura](https://blog.agical.se/en/posts/imagemagick-with-pango-on-macos-ventura/)

Comment: I'm no longer using OSX, but using Docker seems like a good idea if I pick this up in future.